# outbound emails are being stripped of text body and attachments

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

Email client is 2007
Server is Exchange 2007

What would cause the email to be sent as completely blank, only the recipient and subject are still intact.

Same from all clients. Problem has started as of today. Not sure why or where to look.

Please help :(

Comment: I've seen this also, unfortunately no solution yet....

Comment: Any chance you guys run Avast! antivirus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess might be the type of encoding for the emails.  I remember a while back I had problems with emails that were encoded as "Rich Text".  Try switching to HTML or Plain Text and see if that helps anything.

There is also a setting on the Exchange Server that can determine which type of encoding to send.  For example, disable rich text emails server-side.

Comment: Upon checking for the send encoding i noticed there was a rule set up for attachments with PDF files, this was changing the encoding. since there is no need for this rule. we deleted it, and the problem has since stopped.